# Silverlight Application gives 4004 error when trying to use RIA services

Tags: silverlight-4.0, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have written a Silverlight application that is basically an account registration form.  I have been able to successfully deploy this to one of our production servers running windows server 2008/IIS7.  While this took some time to do, I was able to work through and solve the issues that came up fairly easily.  Now I am trying to deploy the application on our main production server.  This server is running windows 2003/IIS6 and this is where I have hit some problems.

I have solved most of the issues and now the silverlight application will load and I can see the form for a few seconds before it disappears.  I believe during this time it is trying to load data from the database using the RIA services.

In IE I get the following error:

```
Webpage error details

Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError       
Message: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 
Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key ApplicationResources [Line: 6 Position: 9]
```

I believe it must be a configuration issue in IIS6 because the app works fine on IIS7 but I am drawing a blank as to what to try.  I have spent hours trying to find a solution to this particular problem and while others have mentioned getting this problem the answers always tend to be non-specific in nature.

This is what I have done so far:

- Added New Application Pool for .NET 4.
- Set the website to use .NET 4 on the ASP.NET tab (nearly had heart failure when this did an iisreset).
- Added the MIME types for Silverlight .xaml, .xap, etc.
- Unchecked Integrated Windows Authentication (was giving an error when checked).
- Give Execute permissions to Scripts and Executables.
- Recycled the application pool.

The one thing I have seen suggested but have not tried is an iisreset, and while I am not entirely convinced that doing this would solve the problem, we have scheduled this to be done tonight (if I cannot find a solution before then).

So basically I am wondering if anyone out there has seen this problem and knows how to solve it?

UPDATE 1: We tried an iisreset last night and as I expected this did **not** solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have the System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.* .dll's set to copy local true in the web project?  Are you able to enable WCF tracing?

Comment: Yes, I have System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework.dll, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll and System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.dll all set to copy local.  I haven't tried WCF tracing yet but I am about to give that a go.  As an experiment I created a new version of the software that doesn't attempt to load from the db using RIA services and the error doesn't occur so the problem is definitely in that area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have solved the problem.  As suggested I did a WCF trace on the application.  This highlighted the **REAL** problem straight away, which was 'The SELECT permission was denied on the object...'.  Once I fixed this the application works as I expected.  It turns out that a colleague of mine had already made this permission change on our other server (running IIS7) so that was why it worked there (this is bad - I know).

Also it didn't help that the javascript error I was receiving on the client side (shown in the question) had nothing to do with the underlying issue and led me well and truly up the garden path.

Comment: That error is like: something bad happened but I don't know what.  That's why you have to do the trace.

Comment: Yeah, I am fairly new to Silverlight Development so it got me this time.  It also explains why there was no consistent solution for fixing it when I went looking.